# How to go through long text and convert it into an Insert statement for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a very long text that looks like this:

1- E.M. Smith, J.P. LAVERGNE, P. VIALLEFONT et J. DAUNIS.
    Recherches en série triazépine-1,2,4.
         J. Heterocyclic Chem. 12, 66 (1975).

2- M. BENCHIDMI et E.M. ESSASSI.
    Synthèse de bis s-triazolo [4,3-b : 4,3-d] triazépines-1,2,4.
    J. Heterocyclic Chem., 13, 885 (1976).

3- LAVERGNE et P. VIALLEFONT.
    Hydrazinolyse d'azabenzodiazépinones et d'azabenzodiazépine-thiones de type 1,5.
    Tetrahedron, 33, 28O7 (1977).

4- E.M. ESSASSI.
"Synthèse et étude de RMN1H en présence de l'Eu(fod)3 des pyrazolo [1,5,4-ef] benzodiazépine-1,5 ones-6
     Bull. Soc. Chim. Belg., 96, 399 (1987).

.
.
.
.

And the list continues for over 300 more, I need to extract each line and add it into an Insert Query for MySql, removing the list numbers and escaping all quotes and double quotes, I have though about using regular expressions but it turns out to be quite difficult for me.

The insert query should look like:

```
INSERT INTO PUBLICATIONS (NAME,AUTHOR,CITE,PUB_YEAR) VALUES
("Recherches en série triazépine-1,2,4.", "E.M. Smith, J.P. LAVERGNE, P. VIALLEFONT et J. DAUNIS.","J. Heterocyclic Chem. 12, 66","1975"), 
( "Synthèse de bis s-triazolo [4,3-b : 4,3-d] triazépines-1,2,4.", "M. BENCHIDMI et E.M. ESSASSI.","J. Heterocyclic Chem., 13, 885","1976" ),
etc.
```

I just gave some format to the text to have some idea but it has no spaces or next lines, it is all in one huge string.

What I have thought is using something like:

```
$string = "all my string"
$pattern = '/regex pattern/';
$replacement = 'result format';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

I realized that splitting it up might be impossible as there is no specific pattern so I could maybe add a \n\r manually to split each line

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:After observations, this kind of pattern can do the job, but i need more data to see all possible exceptions, and to better understand the "logic" of this kind of data. (But the first answer is always a way.)

Some Rules i have seen:

**authors :**

- Begin with eventually with forname initials followed by the name
- All authors are separated by a comma and a space, the last by ~ et ~
- end with a dot and a space

**titles :**

- Begin with uppercase with eventually a qouble quote before
- don't have dots
- don't always ending with a digit:
- - with a comma before and with a dot and a space after
- - or with a - before and a space after
- except if there's no dot at the end

**cites :**

- Begin with uppercase
- differents words with uppercase first letter that can be shorted with a dot
- followed by : comma, space, number, comma space number, space.

**code**

```
$subject = <<<LOD
1- E.M. Smith, J.P. LAVERGNE, P. VIALLEFONT et J. DAUNIS. Recherches en série triazépine-1,2,4. J. Heterocyclic Chem. 12, 66 (1975).
2- M. BENCHIDMI et E.M. ESSASSI. Synthèse de bis s-triazolo [4,3-b : 4,3-d] triazépines-1,2,4. J. Heterocyclic Chem., 13, 885 (1976).
3- LAVERGNE et P. VIALLEFONT. Hydrazinolyse d'azabenzodiazépinones et d'azabenzodiazépine-thiones de type 1,5. Tetrahedron, 33, 28O7 (1977).
4- E.M. ESSASSI. "Synthèse et étude de RMN1H en présence de l'Eu(fod)3 des pyrazolo [1,5,4-ef] benzodiazépine-1,5 ones-6 Bull. Soc. Chim. Belg., 96, 399 (1987).
1O- J.M.F. BOURGOIN-DE-LA-VILLARDIERE. Recherches en série triazepine-1,2,4: 1 - détermination de la structure de la triazolotriazépinone obtenue par action de l'acétylacétate d'éthyle sur le diamino-3,4 triazole-1,2,4 J. Heterocyclic Chem., 13, 885 (1976).
LOD;
$pattern =
 '~# authors :
  (?(DEFINE)(?<FN>(?:[A-Z]\.){0,3}+(?(?<=\.)\h)) ) # ForName
  (?(DEFINE)(?<NM>[A-Z](?:[A-Z]++|[a-z]++)(?:-[A-Z](?:[A-Z]++|[a-z]++))*+)) # NaMe
  [O\d]++-\h(?<author>(?&FN)(?&NM)(?>(,\h(?&FN)(?&NM))*+\het\h(?&FN)(?&NM))?+)\.\h
  # titles :
  "?+(?<title>[A-Z][^.]+?(?:\.|(?:,|-)\d))\h
  # cites :
  (?<cite>(?:[A-Z][a-z]*+\.?+\h)*[A-Z][a-z]*+\.?+,?+\h[O\d]++,\h[O\d]++)\h
  # date :
  \((?<date>[^)]++)\) 
 ~x';               

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {  //cosmetic
    foreach ($match as $key=>$value) {
        if (is_numeric($key)||$key=='NM'||$key=='FN') unset($match[$key]);
    }
} 
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8"/><pre>' . print_r($matches, true) . '</pre>';
```

--*Answer before edit*--

Wow, do you notice there's absolutely nothing to make the difference between Author, Name and Cite. A way is to slice (a simple newline between Author, Name and Cite) that with hand (with about 5s per line, you finish in less than 30min, toutouyoutou:).

I say that because the only difference i see between Author, Name and Cite is the sense that can't be matched with a regex.

If you make this rebarbative work, it will be easy to make the sql query. example:

```
1- E.M. Smith, J.P. LAVERGNE, P. VIALLEFONT et J. DAUNIS.
Recherches en série triazépine-1,2,4.
J. Heterocyclic Chem. 12, 66 (1975).
```

Thats all, no need to touch the number or the date, the regex can do the job.
If you do this work, edit your message to have some help for the regex.

Comment: Too bad, that the E.M. Smith is not written as SMITH. In that case it would by possible to separate the authors, as they all are written in form (((((INITIAL DOT)+ CAPITALISED_WORD_AS_NAME), )+ et )? ((INITIAL DOT)+ CAPITALISED_WORD_AS_NAME))... ;-) But as a matter of fact, its way better to split it by hand, knowing what you do.

Comment: I have find a temporary solution for all the field, but i need much data to treat the execptions. I m going to edit my post.

Comment: thanks! I said at the bottom of my answer I can add breaks to each line to separate author from article from cite from year, so always have 4 lines per entry, manually would take 5 minutes, I guess that would help :) Thanks.